# Bluetooth speakers not working with KDE

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, bluetooth-speaker

After having read quite a [number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423169/get-the-bluetooth-audio-sink-working-with-kubuntu-13-10-and-bose-mini-soundlink) of [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476888/jbl-bluetooth-speakers-play-no-sound-a2dp-off) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488007/connect-to-jbl-bluetooth-speaker) at askubuntu.com and elsewhere I'm still without sound working my bluetooth speakers.

Here's my setup:
I got a Lenovo [Thinkpad X220](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X220) with a Bluetooth daughter card of unknown specifications:

```
user@tp220:~$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
[...]
```

Otherwise the chipset is an Intel Mobile QM67 Express Chipset:

```
user@tp220:~$ lsmod | grep intel
intel_rapl             18783  0 
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
kvm_intel             143590  0 
kvm                   452043  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
snd_hda_intel          30428  6 
snd_hda_controller     31056  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
aesni_intel           152552  1 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd                    79468  24 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device
```

I think I got all the relevant packages installed:

```
user@tp220:~$ LANG=C dpkg -l *blue*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                  Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-=====================================-=======================-=======================-===============================================================================
ii  bluedevil                             2.0~rc1really1.3.2-0ubu amd64                   KDE Bluetooth stack
ii  blueman                               1.23-git201403102151-1u amd64                   Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                             4.101-0ubuntu13         all                     Bluetooth support
ii  bluewho                               0.1-1                   all                     notifies new discovered bluetooth devices
ii  bluez                                 4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-alsa:amd64                      4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   Bluetooth ALSA support
un  bluez-audio                           <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  bluez-btsco                           1:0.50-0ubuntu4         amd64                   Bluez Bluetooth SCO tool
ii  bluez-compat                          4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   BlueZ 3.x compatibility binaries
ii  bluez-cups                            4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-gstreamer                       4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   Bluetooth GStreamer support
un  bluez-hcidump                         <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  bluez-input                           <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  bluez-network                         <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  bluez-serial                          <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  bluez-utils                           4.101-0ubuntu13         all                     Transitional package
un  kdebluetooth                          <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  libbluedevil1:amd64                   2.0~rc1really1.9.4-0ubu amd64                   Qt wrapper for bluez
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                   4.101-0ubuntu13         amd64                   Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth           1:4.0-0ubuntu11         amd64                   Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
un  python-bluetooth                      <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  python-bluez                          0.18-2                  amd64                   Python wrappers around BlueZ for rapid bluetooth development
un  python2.7-bluez                       <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
```

Additionally I installed phonon-backend-vlc after reading somewhere that VLC might be the way to go - to no avail :-/

KDE Bluetooth system successfully bonds to my JBL Charge speakers, I get a message that the audio link (sink?) has been setup successfully.
But - when I open systemsettings -> Multimedia -> Audio Hardware Setup I don't see the audio device, just the internal audio.

I happened to see it once, but then audio got stuck completely and it didn't even come back after reboot. I couldn't open Multimedia settings anymore and finally had to

```
rm .kde/share/config/phonondevicesrc
```

in order to get it back working (after another reboot).

Comment: *push_upwards* anyone?